# How to add new table row with selected values as Text in a new row

Tags: jquery

I have a table row with select dropdown and a text input that should be added to the same table as new row but instead of a select all values should be in a text input, readonly.

What I have is the clone function.
But how to change the select accordingly? Can't figure it.

```
<table id="table-data">
  <tbody>
  <tr id="id1" class="tr_clone"><th>Equipment</th><td>
    <select name="equi[]" id="equi">
    <option value="123">123</option>
    <option value="456">456</option>
    </select>
    <th>QTY</th><td>
      <input type="number" name="qty[]" value="0">
      </td>
      <td align="right">
<a class="add" title="add" data-toggle="tooltip">add</a>
</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>


$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var row = $(e.target).closest('tr'),
copy = row.clone();
copy.insertAfter(row);
});
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/juwxspeo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this line:

```
copy.find("select").val(row.find("select").val())
```

So it will be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(e.target).closest('tr'),
      copy = row.clone();
    copy.insertAfter(row);
    copy.find("select").val(row.find("select").val())
  });
});
```

This will set the select to the same values as the one in the row you clicked.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(e.target).closest('tr'),
      copy = row.clone();
    copy.insertAfter(row);
    copy.find("select").attr("disabled","true")
    copy.find("select").val(row.find("select").val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-data">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id1" class="tr_clone">
      <th>Equipment</th>
      <td>
        <select name="equi[]" id="equi" >
          <option value="123">123</option>
          <option value="456">456</option>
        </select>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="qty[]" value="0">
        </td>
        <td align="right">
          <a class="add" title="add" data-toggle="tooltip">add</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but like this it will be still editable. How can I add a readonly tag to the new row?

Comment: So you want the new select to be readonly? Updated the demo